# Promise: Why simple response has .json, but not Promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

Before I did this, it worked, backend got a HTTP response.

```js
const programId = programIds[0]
await res.unstable_revalidate(`/hu/buyTicket/${programId}`)
return res.json({ revalidated: true })
```

but for multiple call, I get error:

```js
Promise.all(
    programIds.map(
        async (programId: string) =>
            await res.unstable_revalidate(`/hu/buyTicket/${programId}`)
    )
).then((res) => {
    return res.json({ revalidated: true })
})
```

Error:

> Property 'json' does not exist on type 'any[]'

Comment: `res` is an array. A (successful) `Promise.all` promise resolves to an array...

Comment: I am not so familiar with Promise yet, does Promise res has a `flatten` or something?

Comment: While you can flatten an array of arrays into a singly-nested array, you obviously can't "flatten" an array of non-arrays, because what would the result be? It's really not clear what you're trying to do here but you have to deal with the fact that `Promise.all` resolves to an array, which contains the resolutions of each individual promise.

Comment: It looks like you are not interested in that array, and you should just not shadow the global `res` variable with a parameter. So replace `(res) =>` with `() =>`

Comment: You are confusing response object with the result of the `Promise.all` by using the same name: `res`.

Comment: What is `res` in your code? What do you mean by "*backend got a HTTP response*"?